# Bessel bound 

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm a little confuse about this problem:

I have two sequences $\{a_{n}\}$ and  $\{b_{n}\}$ in a Hilbert space $H$, with $\{a_{n}\}$ is a Bessel sequence for $H$ if and only if  $\{b_{n}\}$ is a Bessel sequence for $H$.

The problem is that: If  $\{a_{n}\}$ has Bessel bound $\geq K$, for every $K\in \mathbb N$, does this mean that  $\{a_{n}\}$ is not Bessel sequence, and hence  $\{b_{n}\}$ is also not Bessel sequence?

Definition: A sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is a Bessel sequence in $H$ with Bessel bound $B>0$ if 
$$ \sum_{n} |\langle f,a_{n}\rangle|^{2}\leq B ||f||^{2} $$ for all $f\in H$.

Comment: It maybe worthwhile defining what Bessel sequences and Bessel bounds are. (I know what the former is, but I am not sure I know what you mean by the latter.)

Comment: I did, thanks..

Comment: Then the answer to your question is "yes", $\{a_n\}$ fails the definition of a Bessel sequence.

Comment: Please check the wording of your question.  I can't make head nor tail of it.

Comment: @Willie Could you share your interpretation?  I really have no idea what is being asked here.

Comment: @Glen Let $P(A)$ be the statement that $A = \{a_n\}$ is a Bessel sequence. Assume you know that for some fixed $A,B$ sequences in $H$, $P(A)\iff P(B)$. I interpret the statement $A$ has Bessel bound $\geq K \forall K\in \mathbb{N}$ to mean that $\forall K \exists f\in H$ such that $\sum\langle f,a_n\rangle^2 \geq K\|f\|^2_H$. The OP asks: does this imply $\neg P(A)$ and therefore also $\neg P(B)$. I answer: yes, by definition $\neg P(A)$. By assumed proposition $P(A)\iff P(B)$ we have $\neg P(B)$.